# Is ok, from security point of view , use Oauth 2.0 on my site if it is HTTP not HTTPS?

Tags: facebook, security, oauth

Is ok, from security point of view , use Oauth 2.0 on my site if it is HTTP not HTTPS ?

I am implementing facebook login for my website using "custom flow" (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1)

So, i am redirecting the users here: 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://my.website.url

It prompts the user for facebook login and for authorizing my app (all as expected) and then redirects to http://my.website.url, what they get is something like this:

[http://my.website.url?code=48234932473298437249832743284732984723489237482394732894...500characters...34234234324324#*=*](http://my.website.url?code=48234932473298437249832743284732984723489237482394732894...500characters...34234234324324#_=_)

So, the next step is to use that code to get the AccessToken from facebook, right ?. Now, consider my website is showing on HTTP, if an man-in-the-middle attacker stole that code, he would be able to stole a valid AccessToken as well (by impersonating my server to facebook?). It's supposed to serve the site on HTTPS to prevent this ?

I hope my concern was clear

Comment: Yes, any transmission of confidential information over plain HTTP is bad. Also, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/499/

Comment: The code parameter shared via non secure HTTP can't be used to retrieve the access token from fb api (because the attacker would need the client secret too), so MITM attackers could stole the code parameter, but this ticket isn't enough to get a valid access token. In the context of my project it is enough secure for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be OK with HTTP.

The URL where user is providing his Facebook login/pwd is controlled by Facebook and it is HTTPS. You are right when you say that the authCode itself is useless without the client credentials that your app is having with your code.

Using HTTP/HTTPS on your site is entirely dependent on what information your site holds.